# Decrypting JWE token in golang

Tags: node.js, go, jwe, jose, node-jose

I have this problem, I created a JWE in node.js using [node-jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jose) by this way:

```js
const keystore = [
  {
    kty: 'oct',
    kid: 'QLdRkgyMx_po0fPo5XnOzQQB4iTcyay36m_PA62SBiw',
    k: 'A-OAikjssQZeLkj8N_2Xb9qPBG6lSq10YeLbiTF-kQuM_qKy08jwFqQwsLzn9fmNPkayM9uRg1lHBrPoK_fGtQ'
  }
]

const ks = await jose.JWK.asKeyStore(keystore);
const rawKey = ks.get(keystore[0].kid)
const key = await jose.JWK.asKey(rawKey);
const jwe = await jose.JWE
      .createEncrypt({format: 'compact'}, key)
      .update(payload)
      .final();
```

According to the documentation it is created with `"alg": "PBES2-HS256+A128KW",  "enc": "A128CBC-HS256",` and if I check it in jwt.io, it is.

Then, I need to decrypt in golang, so I do like this using [go-jose.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2"
)

const jweRaw string = "eyJhbGciOiJQQkVTMi1IUzI1NitBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiUUxkUmtneU14X3BvMGZQbzVYbk96UVFCNGlUY3lheTM2bV9QQTYyU0JpdyIsInAyYyI6ODE5MiwicDJzIjoiaVktZEdKaWtYbUZCdXMwRFp5eHdIQSJ9.QkuIGmPojLDX-wpTVTjZRnA093fJRVM6OHkpmoQeyLubahOABg62WQ.z6dm86nWHcWgzmPXiuk0kg.7mOgYF6d9hgfXtTj9RUv7BNuYH-jBAs8px0boOFj1mke_JPetIT44yY7ceffFRfS2QYc6RQMtTvb7vdMArkqeB483g3-tcoCGWxafOb0VfVQHrPTdjpGMLF-9uIJw9z5.RA0Dn-B_Y3kvXYRvVTiNFQ"
const kid string = "QLdRkgyMx_po0fPo5XnOzQQB4iTcyay36m_PA62SBiw"
const k string = "A-OAikjssQZeLkj8N_2Xb9qPBG6lSq10YeLbiTF-kQuM_qKy08jwFqQwsLzn9fmNPkayM9uRg1lHBrPoK_fGtQ"

func main() {
    jwe, err1 := jose.ParseEncrypted(jweRaw)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }
    fmt.Println("jwe", jwe)
    bytes, err2 := jwe.Decrypt(jose.JSONWebKey{Algorithm: "PBES2-HS256+A128KW", Use: "A128CBC-HS256", KeyID: kid, Key: k})
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println("bytes", string(bytes))
}
```

But it panics "panic: square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive"
You can check it here: https://play.golang.org/p/qB3QNtGwBsK

I already tried with https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx but, it doesn't support PBES2-HS256+A128KW algorithm

Thanks.

UPDATE: here's more information:

They key in node was created with this:

```js
const keystore = await jose.JWK.createKeyStore()
const key = await a.generate('oct', 512)
console.log(key.toJSON(true))
```

Then the output was saved in this array:

```js
const keystore = [
  {
    kty: 'oct',
    kid: 'QLdRkgyMx_po0fPo5XnOzQQB4iTcyay36m_PA62SBiw',
    k: 'A-OAikjssQZeLkj8N_2Xb9qPBG6lSq10YeLbiTF-kQuM_qKy08jwFqQwsLzn9fmNPkayM9uRg1lHBrPoK_fGtQ'
  }
]
```

I've been trying create the same JWE with the same JWK in golang and I can decrypt in golang, but neither in node (I got a "key not found" error)... So, cross decrypting doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try https://godoc.org/github.com/square/go-jose

Comment: Same error. That's the version 3.

If I create the JWE in golang and I try to decrypt with node-jose I got a "key not found" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` is a base64url encoded representation of the octet key, unless the go interface specifically mentions passing keys in `JWK` format, which it doesn't, you need to provide the raw key. **`base64url.decode()` the `k` to get the raw key bytes.**

Also, as a sidenote, `PBES2-HS256+A128KW` is intended to be used with passwords, not keys, given it's computationally heavy i'd recommend a different key wrapping algorithm (not a symmetric passphrase based one). You can use asymmetric crypto to encrypt for a recipient. And if you also want to achieve authentication of the message, don't use key wrapping at all, use the Direct Key Agreement from [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) instead.

Comment: and FWIW, the `node-jose` package is doing something awry because i can't decrypt the JWE either, also you're saying it can't decrypt it's own encrypted JWE, which is weird given that this uses entirely symmetric algorithms.

Comment: Yes, that was. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry if said it wrong, but node-jose can decrypt is own JWE. Only cross decrypting was failing.

Comment: This was my successful test: https://play.golang.org/p/AwvHKIZCdKB